# VCR do not want to handle requests inside before and after hooks.

Tags: ruby, rspec, vcr

I developed a ruby wrapper for one HTTP REST API, using rspec with vcr for testing my requests. Project is loaded to travis-ci.org, which automatiacly runs tests all the time.
I have a problem inside my test. VCR can't handle requests inside before and after hooks, implemented to prevent filling server with test data.

```
  describe '.find' do
    before :all do
      @project = Project.new(name: "Project#{Time.now.to_i}").save
    end

    after :all do
      @project.delete
    end

    #tests
  end
```

I got a vcr error:

```
An error occurred in a before(:all) hook.
  VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
```

Of course, I don't want to create and delete a remote entity in each test.

Answer (score 4):

```
  describe '.find' do
    before :all do
      VCR.use_cassette("some_cassette_name") do
        @project = Project.new(name: "Project#{Time.now.to_i}").save
      end
    end

    after :all do
      VCR.use_cassette("some_other_cassette_name") do
        @project.delete
      end
    end

    #tests
  end
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but i need tests really make this responses on Travis-ci, and clean their test data on server after execution, so i can't use vcr cassettes for it.

Comment: If you want to turn VCR off, it provides APIs to do so: https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-5-0/docs/cassettes/error-for-http-request-made-when-no-cassette-is-in-use